# Angularjs unable to populate dropdown dynamically using ng-options

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm displaying a table with user information , below this table there is a input box where user can enter the row index and based on the row index, i'm populating the object dynamically using ng-options.

HTML UI

[image]

After populating dropdown

[image]

After populating dropdown list, all the labels are undefined. Not sure what is the issue.

// html file -

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>AngularFilter</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script src="../lib/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body ng-app="filter">
    <div ng-controller="filterController">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Index</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Date Of Birth</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="employee in data">
                    <th>{{$index + 1}}</th>
                    <th>{{employee.name | lowercase}}</th>
                    <th>{{employee.dob | date:"dd/MM/yyyy"}}</th>
                    <th>{{employee.gender| uppercase}}</th>
                    <th>{{employee.salary | number:2}}</th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter the index of array" ng-model="idx" ng-blur="getSelectedIndex()" />
        <select ng-model="element" ng-options="{{optionString}}" >
            <option value="">select option</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
```

//app.js

```
var module = angular.module("filter", []);
 module.controller("filterController", function($scope) {
$scope.elements={};
$scope.optionString = "e[name] for e in elements";
 var data = [
   {
       name:"Robin",
       dob:new Date("March, 23, 1980"),
       gender:"male",
       salary:70000
   },
   {
       name:"John",
       dob:new Date("January, 23, 1981"),
       gender:"male",
       salary:65000
   },
   {
       name:"Ruby",
       dob:new Date("March, 24, 1982"),
       gender:"female",
       salary:55000
   }
]

$scope.data = data;

$scope.getSelectedIndex =  function() {
   var index = $scope.idx - 1;
   var obj = $scope.data[index];
   for(o in obj) {
       $scope.elements[o] = obj[o];
   }
   console.log($scope.elements)
}
});
```

Comment: What `console.log($scope.elements)` shows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an `object data source` which is `$scope.elements` for `ng-options`

Change your `$scope.optionString` to

```
$scope.optionString = "value as value for (key,value) in elements";
```

See [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) for object data source.

**[FULL EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/7p4k41Lf/4/)**